# Is it correct to add methods in index.js module?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I know that index.js is tipacally used for importing/exporting stuff and make a clean api. But, can it also be used to implement some functionality?

For example, if I have the following directory

```
   /mailing
      index.js
      mail.js
```

and only one method "sendMail()" in mail.js... is it a correct use to move the function implementation directly to index.js, avoinding importing and exporting mail.js on it?

Comment: Sure. It’s fine. Do the simplest thing that gets it done.

Answer (score 0):

Technically yes, but you should avoid to add any.
To add any method, use the best practices to create a component.